# Check for a variable being categorized differently in dataset R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, dataframe

I'm trying to write some sort of function in R that can solve a particular problem for me.

Issue: I have a large dataset of 20,000 observations. Each observation has 13 features, one of them is the city, and the other is the county. I'm trying to think of an efficient way to check whether or not any city appears in different counties.

For instance, I noticed this anomaly in the data:

```
City           |  County
San Francisco  |  San Francisco County
San Francisco  |  Alpine County
```

I'm trying to determine a simple way to check other instances of this.

I considered using

```
table(data$city, data$county)
```

However, it seems error prone since there are 10 counties and hundreds of cities, so trying to manually check seems inconvenient in terms of accuracy.

I'm thinking of a simple for loop with something inside

```
for (x in 1:length(data$city)){
  if (data$city %in%
}
```

I was trying to check if the city appears in multiple counties to see if there were any geographical anomalies or dirty data. However creating a for loop in this context seems more difficult than it should be since R is designed differently than a language such as C++. Can someone help me to create some way to test my problem?

Comment: While you've explained the problem well, I'm afraid this question may get down-voted and closed for being "too broad". If you revise the question to include [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and can point to a more specific stumbling block in your efforts, it will likely be received much better.

Comment: `rowSums(table(unique(df[c("City","County")])))>1`

Comment: The solution worked @Onyambu, I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `tapply()` function:

```
df <- data.frame(City=c( "city1","city2","city3","city1","city2","city5"), 
                 County = c("a", "b","a","b","a","b"))

df$City[which(tapply(df$County, df$City, length) > 1)]
```

This will create the following output:

```
> df$City[which(tapply(df$County, df$City, length) > 1, useNames=FALSE)]
[1] city1 city2
Levels: city1 city2 city3 city5
```

As you can see from the above - it will list which cities are in more than 1 region.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(City) %>% 
  filter(n_distinct(County) > 1) %>% 
  distinct(City)  %>%
  pull(City)
#[1] city1 city2
#Levels: city1 city2 city3 city5
```